# what is Device Registration ID for firebase fcm and where I can extract them?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, pyfcm

```
from pyfcm import FCMNotification

push_service = FCMNotification(api_key="<api-key>")

registration_id = "<device registration_id>"
message_title = "Uber update"
message_body = "Hi john, your customized news for today is ready"
result = push_service.notify_single_device(registration_id=registration_id, message_title=message_title, message_body=message_body)

print result
```

I am working on Pyfcm for push notification, for which i want to get the device registration id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get `token(=device registration_id)`

In my code:

```
String newToken= instanceIdResult.getToken();
```

Maybe in your code:

```
String newToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

so `newToken = device registration_id`

Comment: This is it! Thanx a lot

Comment: can you please explain more, it's a little bit fuzzy